Django manytomany retrieval by order of insertion for input as a queryset to a modelformset_factory
I have two models, Route and Waypoint, and need to preserve the sequence of the waypoints allocated to the route. Route A to B and Route B to A have the same waypoints on the Route (mostly) , but the sequence is reversed.
class Flight_Route(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    departure = models.ForeignKey(Airport,related_name = 'dep_airport',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    arrival = models.ForeignKey(Airport,related_name = 'arr_airport',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exp_flight_time = models.DurationField(null=True,blank=True,default=timedelta(minutes=0))
    alt_arr_airport = models.ForeignKey(Airport,related_name = 'alt_arr_airport',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name + ' alt : ' + str(self.alt_arr_airport.iata_code))
    
    class Meta:  
        verbose_name = 'Flight Route'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Flight Routes'
        ordering = ['name','departure','arrival','exp_flight_time','alt_arr_airport',]

class Waypoint(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=True,blank=True)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=True,blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='Fly-by or Flyover')
    route = models.ManyToManyField(Flight_Route, blank=True, related_name="Waypoint_on_Route")   
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name + ' ' + self.description)
    
    class Meta:  
        verbose_name = 'Waypoint'

I use a model formset_factory on Waypoint in the HTML in order to capture the Waypoints and to add or delete them from the Route. I do not have an additional model to preserve the sequence, as the waypoint_route model generated by Django, has the sequence I need.
class FlightRouteUpdateView(UpdateView,LoginRequiredMixin):
    form_class = FlightRouteForm
    model = Flight_Route
    template_name = 'flight/flight_route_update.html' #<app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    
    def get_named_formsets(self, **kwargs):
        RouteWaypointFormSet = modelformset_factory(Waypoint,form=WaypointForm,fields=('route','name','description','latitude','longitude','type',),exclude=None, extra=0, can_delete=True, can_delete_extra=True)
        if self.request.method == "GET":
            route = self.object
            wps = route.Waypoint_on_Route.through.objects.all()
            return {
                'waypoints': RouteWaypointFormSet(prefix='waypoints', queryset = wps),
            }
        else:
            return {
                'waypoints': RouteWaypointFormSet(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None, prefix='waypoints'),
            } 

When I retrieve the related fields through the Waypoint model, the sequence is the Waypoint_id sequence (i.e. when the waypoint was created). This works fine with the formset, but doesn't give the correct sequence.
My problem which I cannot seem to overcome, is that when I execute the query -through- the waypoint_route model, the sequence is as I want it, but the name of the queryset elements is not recognised by the formset.
I'm sure I'm missing something simple (like a change in the formset declaration or a change to the ManytoMany query) but I cannot seem to overcome this.
prior to the sorted sequence, my extract looked like this :
wps = route.Waypoint_on_Route.all()
with a resulting queryset of :
<QuerySet [<Waypoint: TAVLA South Africa : Limpopo>, <Waypoint: VLS Zambia : Lusaka>, <Waypoint: TIKAN Tanzania : Tikan>, <Waypoint: APNAD Uganda : Lake Victoria>,... ]> 
the correct sequence for the waypoint sequence I retrieve by :
wps = route.Waypoint_on_Route.through.objects.all()
which results in the following queryset  of :
<QuerySet [<Waypoint_route: Waypoint_route object (107)>, <Waypoint_route: Waypoint_route object (108)>, <Waypoint_route: Waypoint_route object (109)>, <Waypoint_route: Waypoint_route object (110)>,...]> 
wps = route.Waypoint_on_Route.through.objects.all().prefetch_related('waypoint') yields exactly the same result as above.
I have tried a number of variations to the query extract : e.g. looping through the queryset and extracting the waypoint instances - but this creates a list, and not a queryset which I can feed into the formset.
I have also tried to extract a value_set('waypoint'), but this is then not recognised by the formset as a queryset.
I currently am seeing the right number of records in the formset display if I use the Waypoint_route object, but the formset data is corrupted and no longer works. (I have tried to extract the Waypoint instances - and can display them in the html, but all the form controls are lost).
 {% with named_formsets.waypoints as formset %}  
                <!-- inline form for waypoints start -->
                    {{ formset.management_form }}
                    <script type="text/html" id="waypoints-template">   
                        <tr id="waypoints-__prefix__" class= hide_all>  
                            {% for fields in formset.empty_form.hidden_fields %}
                                {{ fields }}
                            {% endfor %}            
                            {% for fields in formset.empty_form.visible_fields %}
                                <td>{{fields}}</td>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                    </script>
                    <div class="table-responsive" >
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead class="" style="font-weight: lighter ; color:lightblue">
                                <tr>
                                <th><span style="color: red;" col=2 class="required"> Waypoint*</span> </th>
                                <th><span style="color: steelblue;" col=4 class="required"> Description *</span> </th>
                                <th><span style="color: yellowgreen;" col=2 class="required">Latitude *</span> </th>
                                <th><span style="color: forestgreen;" col=2 class="required">Longitude *</span> </th>
                                <th><span style="color: salmon;" col=1 class="required">Type *</span> </th>
                                <th><span style="color: darkred;">Delete? </span></th>
                                <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="item-waypoints">  <!-- id="item-inlineformsetname" -->
                                <!-- formset non forms errors -->
                                {% for error in formset.non_form_errors %}
                                    <tr><td><span style="color: red">{{ error }}</span></td></tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% for formss in formset %}
                                    {{ formss.management_form }}
                                    <tr id="waypoints-{{ forloop.counter0 }}" class= hide_all>  <!-- id="inlineformsetname-counter" -->
                                        {{ formss.id }}
                                        {% for field in formss.visible_fields %}
                                            <td>
                                                {{field}}
                                                {% for error in field.errors %}
                                                    <span style="color: red">{{ error }}</span>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </td>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <small><a href="#" id="add-image-button" class="btn btn-outline-success add-waypoints">Create New Waypoint</a> </small><!-- id="add-inlineformsetname-button" -->
                    </div>
                {% endwith %}

I have been though all the Django documentation, tried append, and subsets - but stopped at using sql query (as I'm sure there is a better way of resolving this).
I have also tried :
wps = Waypoint.objects.filter(id__in=route.Waypoint_on_Route.through.objects.all().values('route__id').distinct()) 

but the sort sequence from the through model is not maintained
